# How to use routerLinkActive with empty routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following tab bar links and the first one is supposed to be empty:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
          <a md-tab-link [routerLink]="'./'" 
             routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            My tab
          </a>
...
</nav>
```

The link works fine but the active state is not triggered.

What is the proper way to handle empty routerlink for the tab to be activated?

Comment: update the post with routes configured in you app module

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['./'] "
    routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]= "{exact: true}">
    My tab
</a>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Comment: It is not working in my case, Consider a list of <a> tags and I want to apply active class only for clicked <a>. With this solution, Active class is getting applied on all the <a> tags