# Angular sanitizing unsafe URL value javascript:void

Tags: javascript, html, angular, href, angular-router

If have created an a-tag with `href="javascript:void(0)"` so that a click on the link has no effect. But the dev-console says:

> Angular sanitizing unsafe URL value javascript:void

I already tried `[routerLink]="null"` but this does not work as expected, href is filled with the current location.

And omitting `href` completely seems to work, but it does not feel like a proper solution refering to html element integrity.

So what is the proper and valid solution for this case?

Comment: If you want to create a link that doesn't do anything on click, and you want your HTML to be valid, then don't create a link, create a paragraph. A link without an action is simply text.

Comment: Related answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374872/how-to-use-routerlinkactive-with-empty-routerlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374872/how-to-use-routerlinkactive-with-empty-routerlink)

Comment: @SivaRmK thx, this seems to be valid way to go